# In Magento, how can i put an items shipping cost on the product page?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I want to put a shipping cost on the actual product page in Magento, so customers can see how much it will cost them. I can add in the shipping estimator from the basket page. But all i actually want is a line of text under the product price saying shipping from £XX.XX

I have seen this tutorial: http://aneeshsreedharan.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/estimating-shipping-rate-on-product-details-page-in-magento/#comment-10 but it is not working for me on Magento 1.4.2 - i think this an older version is used on this tutorial.

I am using a weight based table rate shipping method at the moment, with only one option.

EDIT: I worked out the problem in the end: Rather embarrasingly I didnt realise the blog was stripping the formatting out. It was changing the ' to a ‘

I can now confirm the code below does display the shipping:

```
<?php
if($_product->isSaleable())
{
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('*');
$quote->addProduct($_product);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

foreach ($rates as $rate)
{
echo $rate->getPrice();
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked out the problem in the end: Rather embarrasingly I didnt realise the blog was stripping the formatting out. It was changing the ' to a ‘

I can now confirm the code below does display shipping:

```
<?php
if($_product->isSaleable())
{
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('*');
$quote->addProduct($_product);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

foreach ($rates as $rate)
{
echo $rate->getPrice();
}
}
?>
```

I have edited my original post - but to confirm the code above works.

Comment: where i need to add this code ? i tried in view.phtml file, but it didt worked for me. i got this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object` in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 424`

Answer (score 3):

Improved it a bit:

```
            <!-- SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
        <?php $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('ES'); // Set your default shipping country here
        $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
        $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);
        $quote->addProduct($_product);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
        // Find cheapest rate
        $cheapestrate = null;
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            if (is_null($cheapestrate) || $rate->getPrice() < $cheapestrate) {
                $cheapestrate = $rate->getPrice();
            }
        }
        $corehelper = Mage::helper('core');
        if ($cheapestrate) {
            echo '<p><strong>Shipping costs:</strong> ' . $corehelper->currency($cheapestrate);?></p>
            <?php
            }else {
            echo "<strong>Free shipping</strong> for this product." ;
        }?>
        <!-- END SHOW SHIPPING RATES-->
```

Btw: This only works with simple products. Haven't had the time yet to call the corresponding simple product.